# Upgrading SQL Server 2008 Standard to Enterprise

Tags: sql-server-2008, upgrade

I'm trying to do the upgrade but when it asks me for the Product Key for the current version, I can't find it. When I go on the MSDN website for it, it says that a key is not necessary for this product. So I'm at a standstill. Do I need to do the upgrade directly from the Enterprise ISO instead of from the Standard SQL Server Installation Center Maintenance Edition Upgrade option? How else can I get the product key?

Or when it asks from what version I'm upgrading, can I select Express or Evaluation where it doesn't require me to put in the current product key?  Will that affect the upgrade?

Will I definitely need the ISO?  The same deal with that is that it says the product key is not necessary on the MSDN website since we have an EA.

Comment: If you have an EA then you should be getting your ISO from the volume license servers, not from MSDN. They are different and the former will require a key (and I'm sure you can retrieve the key through your EA channels). Also, yes, if you use evaluation, it will affect your install - it will work just like Enterprise until 180 days pass, at which time the service will fail to start.

Comment: First of all, let me clarify that I do NOT have access to get these keys and ISOs.  A resource at my client site has the access and I'm just doing the installation.

Yes, I didn't mean from MSDN, but from the volume license servers.  I need the current version (standard) product key to start the upgrade and the upgrade version (enterprise) product key to finish the upgrade but neither are available.  I did get the ISO from the license servers. It's the SQL Server Enterprise R2 SP2.  Is that the correct one if I'm coming from SQL Server Standard R2 SP2.

Comment: And, is that ISO just the service pack, or is it the full version including the service pack?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have access to the volume license servers right now. I do know there is a big difference between `SP2` and `With SP2`.

Comment: Yeah, I plan on installing the Enterprise edition and then SP3 after that.  I don't have to go through the progression of SP1, then 2, then 3, right?

Comment: no, service packs are cumulative; SP3 includes everything in SP1 and SP2.

Answer (score 1):

Have your client with the ISOs or install files open the DefaultSetup file within either the x64 or x86 directory, cut and paste, and send you the text for the SQL Server edition you require. It should look something like:

```
;SQLSERVER2008 Configuration File
[SQLSERVER2008]
PID="AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE"
```

No need to copy/download the whole ISO.